# Network Protocol Error while browsing

Tags: support, error-message, firefox

I get the error shown below while browsing on Firefox. If this is not the right place, let me know; it says to contact the website owner.

As requested, the visible link in the screenshot is: [How do the different propeller configurations compare for wind tunnel purposes?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/59577) (Title has changed since.)

However, the post worked fine after trying again, and it didn't happen just the once (different posts/pages).

[image]

If it is not just a Firefox issue, feel free to update the tags.

Comment: Is this related to [Getting ERR_SSL_BAD_RECORD_MAC_ALERT when browsing Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/379535/4642212)?

Comment: Can you share roughly where  you are in the world, if you use VPN or Tor and if possible which ISP you're using. Also OS and AntiVirus/Firewall software you use. If you can switch to a different network (mobile for example) do you experience the same issues?

Comment: I have the same problem, on Firefox only, regardless of the network (4G or wifi). No VPN/Tor/antivirus, I run macOS. I believe this isn’t a StackExchange issue, but some Firefox bug.

Comment: Also quite sure this is a Firefox issue, I'm having the same problem on Firefox Desktop (and only on SO) but not on Firefox Mobile. This might be relevant: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1528317#c13. At least it appears as if the Firefox people are working on it.